# Stuck while using Ionic cordova build android

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to build my ionic app using `ionic cordova build android` but got stuck here. I also tried `ionic cordova run android` & `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` and also reinstalled cordova and ionic but nothing happened.

> cordova.cmd build android --release
> (node:12112) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
> Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
> ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\egm\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
> Subproject Path: CordovaLib
> Subproject Path: app     "<-- stuck here"

Comment: Which version of `NodeJS` are you using ?

Comment: 14.17.0 latest one

Comment: it recommends setting the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes. I've tried that and nothing changed

Comment: @welkro any update on this ?

Comment: Yes I solved it by uninstalling angular, ionic cordova and removing all files related to them and reinstalled them again. The problem I think is something is overwritten or crashed.